# How to get absolute URL in form action attr using MSHTML getAttribute method?

Tags: mshtml

Here's the deal I have HTML code like this

```
<form action="/test.php">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form>
```

I would like get full url like http://localhost/test.php calling getAttribute ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752280(v=vs.85).aspx )

I'm trying to do it with the following code (Delphi)

```
formAction := form.getAttribute('action', 4);
```

but it only shows '/test.php'. How to make it work?

// Sorry for my bad english

Comment: If you think that this question has been answered then please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get obtain the current URL from iwebbrowser2
2. Do a string operation and get the complete URL.

Hope it helps.

Comment: 1. No, I'm using IHTMLDocument2. 2. What does it mean? Please, explain

Comment: @user1239398: I am assuming that you must have obtained the IHTMLDocument2, from an Instance of IWebBrowser2, by calling the get_Document(). From that IWebBrowser2 instance you can obtain the url of the page is currently loaded in the browser. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not the solution as current location can be different from action e.g we are at http://localhost/test.php, but form action can be just '/post.php'

Comment: @user1239398 Save the string which you get before the last occurence of /, lets say s1=localhost. Now concatenate with the form action. I think you should get the url you needed.